# Cast object in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to cast a List to my custom list which is ProjectList

```
IList<Project> projects = cm.GetOrAdd("projectList", () => (ProjectList)ProjectService.GetAllProjects().ToList(), new CacheItemPolicy(5));
```

ProjectList contains only:

```
public class ProjectList : List<Project>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Projects: {0}", this.Count());
    }
}
```

However it's giving a runtime error that it cant cast the object.

Error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[sidc.Framework.Data.Entities.Project]
>   can't be converted to type sidc.Framework.Web.Helpers.ProjectList.

Am I overseeing something? I'm using the lambda because my cm (CacheManager) will evaluate the `Func<>` when the object is not in cache.

Comment: `(ProjectList)ProjectService.GetAllProjects().ToList()` should be `(List<ProjectList>)ProjectService.GetAllProjects().ToList()`

Comment: @DZL That wouldn't work either as you cannot cast `List<Project>` to `List<ProjectList>`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is unclear to you? That cast is simply invalid.

Comment: I agree, show your model, If `ProjectList` contains `List<Project>` you could use `ProjectService.GetAllProjects().ToList().SelectMany(pl => pl.Projects)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't downcast a `List<T>` to any type that inherits from `List<T>`, because the runtime can't fill in the blanks for you. It wouldn't know how to create a "Dog" from an "Animal". That's what the compiler tries to tell you.

Add a constructor that accepts an enumerable of `Project`, and populates itself with that list:

```
public class ProjectList : List<Project>
{
    public ProjectList() { }
    public ProjectList(IEnumerable<Project> projects)
        : this()
    {
        this.AddRange(projects);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Projects: {0}", this.Count());
    }
}
```

Then change your lambda from:

```
() => (ProjectList)ProjectService.GetAllProjects().ToList()
```

To:

```
() => new ProjectList(ProjectService.GetAllProjects())
```

But by introducing a concrete type (`ProjectList` for `List<Project>`) you're pretty much annihilating the use of generics: not having to specify a type per record type. You probably don't need `ProjectList` at all.

Comment: The only reason of ProjectList is to use the overide ToString method.

Comment: Depending on why you need that, you can solve it in a different way.

Comment: Mu cachemanager accepts any type of object. I have a cache manager debug page that shows more info about the objects. That is where i use tostring as the debug page doest know anything about the objects

Comment: Debugging shouldn't be invasive. With some type checking and maybe some reflection you can easily print `List<Project>.Count = {0}`.

Comment: I agree but some other cached objects are more complex. I may as well skip as it is really debug.

Comment: You still don't want to alter your code for debugging. See [Change “ToString” for a sealed class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120998/change-tostring-for-a-sealed-class) for some hints.

Comment: I'll look into it, looks (to me) more complex as I will have to evaluate each component in the cache, and also the ones I do not have in control (plugins).

Answer (score 0):

This is just how inheritance works - you can cast `ProjectList` to `List<Project>`, but not the other way - `List<Project>` is not of type `ProjectList`